# "Interconnect" as a noun

Tags: meaning, nouns

I have frequently seen the verb "interconnect" used as a noun where I think that it should rather be "interconnection", but I cannot find any information about this in dictionaries like [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=interconnect&oldid=47712022), which only cover the word as a verb.

If you try to Google "[an interconnect](http://archive.is/G1BAn)" you will find over 300,000 results

Is this simply a mistake?
If so, is the mistake so common that it is acceptable usage? 
Also, is there any semantic difference between "an interconnection" and "an interconnect"?
Is this usage more common in certain dialects or sociolects?

I should add that I am not referring to cases where the past participle ending -ed is dropped from a verb.

Comment: I checked on Google for 'interconnect' as a noun. Here's what I found -noun
noun: interconnect; plural noun: interconnects "a device used to connect two things together."

Comment: ODO and Collins list the noun usage; the fact that M-W, AHD, Macmillan, CED ... don't shows that it's currently being accepted into the lexicon. I'd say that 'interconnection' is more associated with the overarching concept of connectivity rather than an individual example, thus being the favoured version for non-count / more abstract usage.

Comment: I am familiar with *interconnect* only as [technical jargon](https://spectrum.ieee.org/energy/the-smarter-grid/the-blackout-of-2003). I cannot think of a situation where I would not favor *connection* over *interconnection* or *interconnect*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collins English Dictionary—Complete and Unabridged 12th edition, actually covers this meaning of the word [Interconnect](https://www.tfd.com/interconnect). It refers to the concrete items which interconnect together. It is common enough to use the word this way in certain cants involving electronic or even general purpose engineering. A computer cable, or the plug on either side of it would be referred to as interconnects. [You can see that Amazon.com has a section called cables and interconnects section with a subsection for U.S.B. cables for instance](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=lp_464394_hi_4?rh=n%3A172282%2Cn%3A%21493964%2Cn%3A541966%2Cn%3A172456%2Cn%3A172463&ie=UTF8&qid=1518746465):

[image: This is a screenshot of the aforementioned section, showing various U.S.B. cables that links to archive.is, just in case the Amazon page ever changes.]

Compare to [The Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia's](http://www.micmap.org/dicfro/search/century-dictionary/Interconnect) definition, which refers to *the state of being interconnected*. Once you plug the U.S.B. cable into your computer and printer, you have established a (physical) interconnection between them, which allows them to communicate:

> An important special case when interconnecting systems (e.g. plant and controller) is the so called full interconnection case, i.e., the 
>   situation that all the variables are available for interconnection.
>
> ---
>
> [Modelling and Control of Dynamical Systems: Numerical Implementation in a Behavioral Framework](https://books.google.com/books?id=cyQAg4uVKGsC&lpg=PA35&pg=PA35#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Ricardo Zavala Yoe (©2008)

When you unplug the cable, you sever that interconnection:

> Neither party may sever the interconnection without the approval of the national telecom authority. If a malfunction occurs in the network interconnection's communications technology, the parties shall promptly take effective measures to eliminate it. [—[Cyber Law in China](https://books.google.com/books?id=UtL3Cw-LwUYC&lpg=PA37&dq=%22sever%20the%20interconnection%22&pg=PA37#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Hong Xue (©2010)]

As for appropriateness and commodity, I feel that it is worth noting that there are older, more specific and easier to discern alternatives to interconnect as a noun, such as [connector](http://www.micmap.org/dicfro/search/century-dictionary/connector) and [coupler](http://www.micmap.org/dicfro/search/century-dictionary/coupler). These are also more common and as shown by [this Google ngrams chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+coupler%2Ca+connector%2Can+interconnect&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ca%20coupler%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20coupler%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BA%20coupler%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20Coupler%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ca%20connector%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20connector%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BA%20connector%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20Connector%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Can%20interconnect%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ban%20interconnect%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAn%20interconnect%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ban%20Interconnect%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAn%20Interconnect%3B%2Cc0):

[image: A screenshot of the google ngrams, which linkd to an archive on archive.is]

Due to their trifecta of priority, popularity, and precision I would generally advise using the alternatives first.